# Hive Load Data Inpath overwrite on text format file causing duplicate SKEY column values

Tags: hive, hdfs, beeline

Trying to load a well-formatted ~80GB text file (CHR 01 delimited) into Hive through beeline:

```
beeline -u "<connector:server:port>;principal=<principal_name>"  \
-e "LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/hdfs/dir' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE database.tableName;"
```

The table was created with the correct/appropriate schema & datatypes (100s of columns), with the following parameters:

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

When the data is loaded it appears that all the columns have the correct information - at least the same order of magnitude of the input (10's of millions of records), sampling of the values in the columns match the expected values; however the first column (coincidentally, the SKEY) is duplicated severely - as it were applied to the records below its first occurrence.

```
SKEY     ValA ValB ValC ValD
Record1  1    2    3    Apple
Record2  7    12   22   Baseball
Record3  9    28   10   Tennis
Record4  6    2    3    Jeans
...
RecordN  8    4    12   Wishbone
...
```

Becomes:

```
SKEY     ValA ValB ValC ValD
Record1  1    2    3    Apple
Record1  7    12   22   Baseball
Record1  9    28   10   Tennis
....
Record4  6    2    3    Jeans
Record4  8    4    12   Wishbone
...
```

Anyone have experience overcoming this issue, or have an idea about the root cause? I believe I can get better results with another format (ie/ AVRO) but it's a little unsatisfactory.

Is there a maximum limit on textfile import to Hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the data type of the column key?

--Updated after looking at boethius comments----

I would advise you to use String, big int or decimal for your primary key. With float you lose precision. e.g. if you have two skeys 8611317762 and 8611317761. I suspect as float they are both interpreted as 8.611317762 x 10^10. And that is why distinct is returning a wrong answer.

Comment: This is better served as a comment - I am loading it as a float, currently - it is coming from the source system as a DECIMAL

Comment: I would advise you to use String, big int or decimal for your primary key. With float you lose precision. e.g. if you have two skeys 8611317762 and 8611317761. I suspect as float they are both interpreted as 8.611317762 x 10^10. And that is why distinct is returning a wrong answer.

Comment: Wow! That's an 'interesting' feature of floats! I will keep that in mind in the future..